# Modifying Audio Files using CSound

Tags: csound

Currently i am trying to create a game and having a radio which you must tune. I was experimenting using Csound and Frequency modulation and while it is possible using oscoil opcode however It does not appear to allow you to modify a Sound File from the DiskIn opcode.

Is there another opcode that may allow modification to an audio diskin File?

Answer (score 0):

Could you explain what you mean about "modifying a sound file from the diskin opcode"? I know you can modulate the playback rate at k-rate but I'm not sure that's what you're looking tod o.